# Default instance for a named instance miss

Tags: c#, structuremap

Is there a way to initialize StructureMap such that we wouldn't get this exception text:

> Could not find an Instance name "X" for PluginType ISomeInterface.

... but instead received a default implementation of the type?

Example code below:

```
[Test]
public void OnNamedMiss()
{
    ObjectFactory.Initialize(i =>
    {
        i.For<IX>().Use<Alpha>().Named("alpha");
        i.For<IX>().Use<Bravo>().Named("bravo");
        i.For<IX>().Use<Charlie>().Named("charlie");

        // define default?
    });

    // Can I make this return Default instead of throwing?
    var x = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<IX>("delta");
}

public interface IX { }
public class Default : IX { }
public class Alpha : IX { }
public class Bravo : IX { }
public class Charlie : IX { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
var x = ObjectFactory.TryGetInstance<IX>("delta") ?? ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IX>();
```

provided that you have registered the `Default` class as a default instance. The `Use` method registers default instances and the `Add` method adds additional instances.

```
i.For<IX>().Use<Default>();
i.For<IX>().Add<Alpha>().Named("alpha");
i.For<IX>().Add<Bravo>().Named("bravo");
i.For<IX>().Add<Charlie>().Named("charlie");
```

Comment: I re-read the question and realized you wanted the `Default` class as default, not the c# default instance. Edited in a new solution for that.